# Trying to use a .env file inside my project

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, heroku, environment-variables

I have a backend that was working without errors, so I'm trying to send it to Heroku Server, as it is my first trying with Heroku, I've chosen a free database (JawsDB MySQL), but trying to change my local database MySQL to the one on Heroku my .env file is not working anymore, I've already tried to change several things there, but I have always an error related to my .env file

```
.env:6
    DB_HOST=qao3ibsa7hhgecbv.cbetxkdyhwsb.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com,
```

Installing my database on MySQL workbench I get no errors, but I can't find a way to set it on my .env file
Here is my .env file:

```
require('dotenv').config();

module.expots = {
  authSecret: 'myauthsecret',
  db: {
    DB_HOST=dbhost.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com,
    DB_USER=dbuser,
    DB_PASSWORD=dbpassword
    DB_PORT=3306,
    DB_DATABASE=dbname
  }
}
```

My auth secret is used by the passport.js

And here is my knexfile.js where I set my database credentials:

```
const { db } = require('./.env');

module.exports = {
  client: 'mysql2',
  connection: {db,
    mysqlhost: process.env.DB_HOST,
    username: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    database: process.env.DB_DATABASE
  },
  pool: {
    min: 2,
    max: 10
  },
  migrations: {
    tableName: 'knex_migrations'
  }
};
```

I have no idea what can be so wrong with that, On my local machine I used to set my .env like this:

```
module.exports = {
  authSecret: 'sqt;n/eP-kX-(J#I#8WahB|uhx/i)^$aZ[ZD!PADRZ#Qn@^s;Sl]~wI?3ADxF',
  db: {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: '3306',
    user: 'root',
    password : 'aPassword',
    database : 'database'
  }
}
```

And it was working, now I have no idea what I should do to make it working with my database on Heroku...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is because your are loading the `.env` as JS code and the `db` object is not valid JS. It should be like this to be valid JS:

```js
module.expots = {
  authSecret: 'myauthsecret',
  db: {
    DB_HOST: "dbhost.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
    DB_USER: "dbuser",
    DB_PASSWORD: "dbpassword",
    DB_PORT: 3306,
    DB_DATABASE: "dbname",
  }
}
```

That said, there is a misunderstanding on what a `.env` file should have and how to use it. The correct `.env` content shoul be just:

```
# .env
# Replace with the correct values 
DB_HOST=dbhost.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
DB_USER=dbuser
DB_PASSWORD=dbpassword
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=dbname
```

Then in your `knexfile.js` you do:

```js
// This loads the .env variables into the process.env 
require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = {
  client: 'mysql2',
  connection: {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    username: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    database: process.env.DB_DATABASE
  },
  ...
};
```

Comment: If I try to use it this way, it is accepted, but it doesn't validate my code because I need the secret I'm storing on .env, so what should I do with my secret that is for the passport?

Comment: @GNeto this part `require('dotenv').config();` in the `knexfile.js` loads the `.env` file variables into the `process.env` object. 
In the `.env` file you should replace the values with the ones for your application and keep that content secret (never commit the `.env` file to git).
In your different environments (development / production / staging) you need to create a different `.env` file for each one with the credentials that correspond to the DB you are using there.

Comment: Thanks, I have solved it modifying all my back-end that was created in different way, it also wouldn't accept if I tried using require('dotenv').config(); because it was setted as ajavascript file instead of a dotenv file.

Answer (score 0):

**server.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import cors from 'cors';
import routes, { notFoundRoute } from './routes';
import errorHandler from './errorHandler';
```

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const app = express();

const config = () => {
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(express.json());
  app.use(cors());
};

const serve = async () => {
  app.use('/api/v2/', routes());
  app.use(notFoundRoute);
  app.use(errorHandler);

  app.listen(port, () => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log(`Server is up on port ${port}`);
  });
};

const init = async () => {
  config();
  await serve();
};

init();


Package.json
     {...

     "type": "module",
     "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon --experimental-modules --es-module-specifier- 
    resolution=node -r dotenv/config server.js"},
```